# What is the effect of the composition $f ∘ g ∘ f^{−1}$ on g?

Tags: permutation-cycles

Let f = (4 5 6) and g = (1 9 8 4)(2 7 5)(3 6) be two permutations in S<sub>9</sub>.

Then $f ◦ g ◦ f^{−1}$ = (1 9 8 5)(2 7 6)(3 4)

What is the effect of such a composition on g?

I can see 2 potential similarities. The first one is that the 4 5 and 6 have been replaced by the image of $f$. The second has nothing to do with $f$ and the end values in each cycle for $g$ has been pushed once. I'm really not too sure.

I can see a similarity, 4 5 and 6 have been replaced by the image of f but then I'm doubting myself and thinking the actual values in f have no effect on g.

For example, how would this look like in the follow proposition:

Let n be a positive integer and let f,g ∈ S<sub>n</sub>. Suppose
that the cycle notation for g is
(a<sub>1,1</sub> a<sub>1,2</sub> ··· a<sub>1,k1</sub>
)···(a<sub>m,1</sub> a<sub>m,2</sub> ···a<sub>m,km</sub>
).
Then the cycle notation for $f ◦ g ◦ f^{−1}$ is ...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120971/conjugate-permutations-in-s-n-and-or-a-n

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks but I'm still having a hard time finding what conjugate means in regards to my context. could you explain a bit further sorry for the hassle

Comment: Your first idea is good, but the statement can go further.  Does this replacement only apply to $4,5,6$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr No, do the rest of the values in f that completes S9 also apply? So 1 1, 2 2 etc..

Comment: So f◦g◦f−1 is conjugate to g since f,f-1 exists but how would you put that into the proposition?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Wait I think I got it. Is the cycle notation for f g f-1 = (f(a1,1),f(a,1,2)...)?

Comment: You can make up your own example to see if your formula works.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes it works wow. That's really interesting to see how that works. Intuitively, how is f involved in this?

Comment: If you apply $f\circ g\circ f^{-1}$ to $f(x)$, then you get $f(g(x))$